# Finding which rows have duplicates in a .csv, but only if they have a certain amount of duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, duplicates

I am trying to determine which sequential rows have at least 50 duplicates within one column. Then I would like to be able to read which rows have the duplicates in a summarized manner, ie

```
    start end total
    9     60  51
    200   260 60
```

I'm trying to keep the start and end separate so I can call on them independently later.
I have this to open the .csv file and read its contents:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv("BN4 A4-F4, H4_row1_column1_watershed_label.csv", header=None)
    
    df.groupby(0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
```

Which gives me this:

```
0
0   52.0
1   65.0
2   52.0
3   52.0
4   52.0
... ...
4995    8.0
4996    8.0
4997    8.0
4998    8.0
4999    8.0
5000 rows × 1 columns
```

I'm having a number of problems with this. 1) I'm not sure I totally understand the second function. It seems like it is supposed to group the numbers in my column together. This code:

```py
    df.groupby(0).count()
```

gives me this:

```
    0
    0.0
    1.0
    2.0
    3.0
    4.0
    ...
    68.0
    69.0
    70.0
    71.0
    73.0
    65 rows × 0 columns
```

Which I assume means that there are a total of 65 different unique identities in my column. This just doesn't tell me what they are or where they are. I thought that's what this one would do

```py
    df.groupby(0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
```

but if I change the 0 to anything else then it screws up my generated list.

Problem 2) I think in order to get the number of duplicates in a sequence, and which rows they are in, I would probably need to use a for loop, but I'm not sure how to build it. So far, I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to figure it out but I just don't think I know Python well enough yet.

Can I get some help, please?

**UPDATE**

Thanks! So this is what I have thanks to @piterbarg:

```py
#function to identify which behaviors have at least 49 frames, and give the starting, ending, and number of frames
def behavior():
    df2 = (df
        .reset_index()
        .shift(periods=-1)
        .groupby((df[0].diff() != 0).cumsum()) #if the diff between a row and the prev row is not 0, increase cumulative sum
        .agg({0 : 'mean', 'index':['first','last',len]})) #mean is the behavior category
    df3 = (df2.where(df2[('index','len')]>49) 
        .dropna() #drop N/A
        .astype(int) #type = int
        .reset_index(drop = True))
    print(df3)
```

```py
out:
0 index           
  mean first  last  len
0    7    32    87   56
1   19   277   333   57
2    1   785   940  156
3   30  4062  4125   64
4   29  4214  4269   56
5    7  4450  4599  150
6    1  4612  4775  164
7    7  4778  4882  105
8    8  4945  4999   56
```

The current issue is trying to make it so the dataframe includes the last row of my .csv. If anyone happens to see this, I would love your input!

Comment: You only care about consecutive duplicates, right?

Comment: That's right, and only if there are 50 consecutive duplicates in the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by mocking a df:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(314)
df=pd.DataFrame({0:np.random.randint(10,size = 5000)})
# make sure we have a couple of large blocks
df.loc[300:400,0] = 5 
df.loc[600:660,0] = 4
```

First we identify where the changes to the consecutive numbers occur, and `groupby` each of such groups. We record where it starts, where it finishes, and the size of each group

```
df2 = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby((df[0].diff() != 0).cumsum())
        .agg({'index':['first','last',len]})
        )
```

Then we only pick those groups that are longer than 50

```
(df2.where(df2[('index','len')]>50)
    .dropna()
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index(drop = True)
    )
```

output:

```
    index
    first   last    len
0   300     400     101
1   600     660     61
```

For your question as to what `df.groupby(0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)` does, as far as I can tell it does nothing. It groups by different values in column 0 and then discard those groups whose size is 0, which is none of them by definition. So this returns your full df

### Edit

Your code is not quite right, should be

```
def behavior():
    df2 = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby((df[0].diff() != 0).cumsum())
        .agg({0 : 'mean', 'index':['first','last',len]}))
    df3 = (df2.where(df2[('index','len')]>50)
        .dropna()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(drop = True))
    print(df3)
```

note that we define and return `df3` not df2, and also I amended the code to return the value that is repeated in the `mean` column (sorry names are not very intuitive but you can change them if you want)

`first` is the index when the repetition starts, `last` is the last index, and `len` is how many elements there.

Comment: Thanks, Piterbard! I wrote another answer because it made the coding more clear. Can I please get your thoughts again?

Comment: Hallelujah, I cannot explain how excited I am to tear this thing apart and see how this works. Thank you soo much!! I may reply again and ask more questions if I can't figure out how something works. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm writing another answer to show you something I noticed just now

Comment: Actually, the shift thing did work! I'll edit my question. But I still can't see the last row of my csv in the dataframe. As always I'll see if I can figure it out, but if anyone happens to catch this ahead of time, I would love input!

Answer (score 0):

```py
#function to identify which behaviors have at least 49 frames, and give the starting, ending, and number of frames
def behavior():
    df2 = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby((df[0].diff() != 0).cumsum()) #if the diff between a row and the prev row is not 0, increase cumulative sum
        .agg({0 : 'mean', 'index':['first','last',len]})) #mean is the behavior category
        .shift(-1)
    df3 = (df2.where(df2[('index','len')]>49) 
        .dropna() #drop N/A
        .astype(int) #type = int
        .reset_index(drop = True))
    print(df3)
```

yields this:

```
  0 index           
  mean first  last  len
0    7    31    86   56
1   19   276   332   57
2    1   784   939  156
3   31  4061  4124   64
4   29  4213  4268   56
5    8  4449  4598  150
6    1  4611  4774  164
7    8  4777  4881  105
8    8  4944  4999   56
```

Which I love. I did notice that the group with 56x duplicates of '7' actually starts on row 32, and ends on row 87 (just one later in both cases, and the pattern is consistent throughout the sheet). Am I right in believing that this can be fixed with the shift() function somehow? I'm toying around with this still :D